# How to add a new plugin in karma's configuration file

Tags: javascript, karma-runner

I wanted to generate an HTML test report from karma, so I used the plugin [`karma-htmlfile-reporter`](https://github.com/matthias-schuetz/karma-htmlfile-reporter). I followed the instruction of that plugin. However, the setting below tripped me over:

```
plugins : [
      'karma-htmlfile-reporter'
    ],
```

It turns out that this will overwrite the default `plugins` setting and, unsurprisingly, break some of the things. I ended up using something like below to make it work, which basically manually lists all items I needed:

```
  plugins : [
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-htmlfile-reporter'
  ],
```

Albeit not too much extra work and code, it seems dumb. So, is there a better way to add a new plugin in karma's configuration file?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try just to add it to the reporters once installed, which is cleaner and in theory Karma should load all the `karma-*` plugins it finds scanning the modules.

```
// karma.conf.js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    ...
    // Just add it here
    reporters: ['progress', 'html'],

    // Specific plugin configuration
    htmlReporter: {
      outputFile: 'tests/units.html'
    }
  });
};
```

Sometimes it the finder doesn't work properly so you have to explicitly say Karma what to load, so you have to do what you've written.